# Add script in existing web page in order to remove the content

Tags: javascript, html, web, tags

Ok, here is my problem.
I made researches on Ebay with worldwild results, but I don't want to see results from China.
Is it possible to add/load a script, this script will remove all tags containing "china" (actualy the "li" parent tag).
I can develope the script but I don't how to insert it, and if it is possible.
I hope that I am clear enough.

Comment: Please share some sample code. It will help to understand exact problem. Do you use jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to ebay.com, perform a search, and open Google Chrome's console, you may run repeatedly the script below, in order to clear China results from screen. PS: As my language is Portuguese, I have assigned the value "De China" to the variable `searchText`, but you should change it, depending on what language is going to be displayed on your screen results (maybe "From China", if it is English).

```
var listOfChinaLabelNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("s-item__location s-item__itemLocation");
var searchText = "De China";

for (var i = 0; i < listOfChinaLabelNodes.length; i++) {
    if (listOfChinaLabelNodes[i].textContent == searchText) {
        var attrValue = listOfChinaLabelNodes[i].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.attributes[1].nodeValue;
        var attrValueWithQuotationMarks = "'" + attrValue + "'";
        var dataViewToBeSelected = "li[data-view=" + attrValueWithQuotationMarks + "]";
        document.body.querySelector(dataViewToBeSelected).remove();
    }
}
```